# Is there a way to sort Javascript functions alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

Is there a way to sort Javascript Functions (the code itself) alphabetically using Sublime Text or other tool?

For example taking this:

```
a(){
},
c(){
},
b(){
}
```

And sorting it to this:

```
a(){
},
b(){
},
c(){
}
```

Comment: Probably better asking [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as this is not strictly a programming related issue rather a software related issue.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I'd group methods by their functionality, not by their name.

Comment: @Bergi I name methods based on their functionality, so sorting them alphabetically makes sense.